# After upgrade to rails 6.1.3, Active Storage return a 403 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6.1

After an upgrade to rails 6.1.3, Aws return a 403 error for `image_tag @item.photos.first`.
All variants are displayed without any error.

**item.rb**

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :photos, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**items_controller**

```
  def show
    @item = Item.find[params[:id]
  end
```

**items/show.html.erb**

```
<% if @item.photos.attached?%>
            <%= image_tag(@item.photos.first,
              srcset: [
                        [url_for(photos_variants(@item.photos.first, 300, 180)), "375w"],
                        [url_for(photos_variants(@item.photos.first, 500, 300)), "512w"],
                        [url_for(photos_variants(@item.photos.first, 750, 450)), "768w"],
                        [url_for(photos_variants(@item.photos.first, 1000, 600)), "1024w"],
                        [url_for(photos_variants(@item.photos.first, 1500, 900)), "1980w"]
                      ],
              sizes: "100vw",
              alt: @item.name) %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I get a 403 error only for the first <%= image_tag(@item.photos.first,

Comment: I really have no idea where that image is being loaded from and I can not even imagine what it could be...

Comment: I added some infos like model, controller and view